# Unable to initialize bean cxf?

Tags: osgi, cxf, apache-karaf, karaf, blueprint-osgi

currently i'm working on karaf prject, i have deployed 3 bundle module-data, module-service and module-jaxrs with Active status, then when i configured  karaf feature to automaticaly deploy jar's the status of module-jaxrs became 
failure beacause of cxf. i have tried everything but always the same error.

The result of diag:

```
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Unable to initialize bean cxf
                at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.runBeanProcInit(BeanRecipe.java:714)
                at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:824)
                at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:787)
                at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)



    Caused by: org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not create object of extension class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngineImpl.
            at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.load(Extension.java:241)
            at org.apache.cxf.bus.osgi.CXFExtensionBundleListener$OSGiExtension.load(CXFExtensionBundleListener.java:145)
```

here is the blueprint:

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxws"
           xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs"
           xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/core"

           xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
  http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/jaxws.xsd
  http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/jaxrs.xsd
  http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/core.xsd">

    <!-- Configuration des logs CXF afin de faire apparaître les requetes recues et les reponses fournies, dans le journal de Karaf -->
    <cxf:bus id="bus">
        <cxf:features>
            <cxf:logging/>
        </cxf:features>      
    </cxf:bus>

    <!-- Configuration du endpoint JAX-RS dans le container OSGI-->
       <jaxrs:server address="/tuto" id="tut">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref component-id="customerRestService"/>
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>        
    </jaxrs:server>


    <!-- Declaration du bean customerRestService implemente par le POJO com.exemple.karaf.jaxrs.CustomerRestService-->
       <!-- Ce bean possede une propriete a injecter. L'injection de cette propriete (ici une instance de la classe CustomerService) est faite
       immediatement apres la creation du bean  -->
    <bean id="customerRestService" class="com.exemple.customerRestFulHibernateWS.jaxrs.CustomerRestService">
        <property name="customerService" ref="customerService"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Definition des dependances -->
    <reference id="customerService" interface="com.exemple.customerRestFulHibernateWS.services.CustomerService"></reference>
</blueprint>
```